# How to align one line in a textbox c#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a calculator where the result of the calculation should display on the right side instead of the left.

Unfortunately, you can't use `tbx_main.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Right;` since it makes the whole text align on the right. It would really be useful if there was a way like `\t` where that row only gets dragged to the right. I'm unsure if there even is a solution to this...

Comment: what are you using as framework ? WPF ? Winforms ? Do you have any minimal code to share as example ?

Comment: (note : in WPF, this is actually quite easy)

Comment: Try `RichEditTextbox` in case of *WinForms*: you can format out a *paragraph* (with calculation results), not the entire text

Comment: could you please post the code you have so far and a screenshot of the result you are getting now?

Comment: You can use a monospace font like Consolas and format the string accordingly. With a monospace font you know exactly how many characters fit in the textbox and you can pad the string to make it have this length.

Comment: _I'm unsure if there even is a solution to this..._ No, there isn't beyond Olivier's comment. Why restrict yourself to one textbox only?

Comment: "since it makes the whole text align on the right." - This statement implies that you are putting more than just the result in the textbox.   If that is the case, you should use separate controls for each element and format them accordingly.  Also consider looking at the TableLayoutPanel where each cell within the table is allowed to be justified independently.  A screenshot of your design would help greatly.

Answer (score 1):

you can use TextBox.TextAlign Property if you are are using Windows Forms

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox.textalign?view=netframework-4.8

for WPF 
TextBox.TextAlignment Property for WPF
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.textbox.textalignment?view=netframework-4.8